# Time zone conversion in PostgreSQL without timezone does the opposite operation

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, timezone

Query:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-10-24 20:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') as d,
      (TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-10-24 20:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') at time zone 'utc')::timestamptz at time zone 'ASIA/CALCUTTA' as ist_w_tz,
      (TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-10-24 20:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') at time zone 'utc')::timestamp at time zone 'ASIA/CALCUTTA' as ist_wo_tz
```

Result:

```
d:         2021-10-24 20:00:00+00
ist_w_tz:  2021-10-25 01:30:00    -- Correct
ist_wo_tz: 2021-10-24 14:30:00+00 -- Opposite, its -5:30 rather than +5:30
```

Why does this happen? In the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) (section 8.5.1.3), it is specified that timestamp without timezone is considered to be in the local timezone. Shouldn't then the conversion without timezone be like

1. 2021-10-24 20:00 without tz so assumes it to be local i.e IST so converts it to UTC
2. 20:00 - 05:30 = 14:30
3. Then to IST 14:30 + 05:30 = 20:00

Ran this using pgadmin4, `select version()` returns

> PostgreSQL 13.4 (Debian 13.4-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit

Comment: "In the docs (section 8.5.1.3), it is specified that timestamp without timezone is considered to be in the local timezone."  The docs don't say that.  Please quote the wording you are interpreting that way.

Answer (score 3):

The main confusion seems to be that ...

- ... your 2nd expression `ist_w_tz` is type `timestamp without time zone`.
- ... your 3rd expression `ist_wo_tz` is type `timestamp with time zone`.

While your column names imply the opposite.

The [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) construct translates `timestamptz` to `timestamp` and vice versa, that's **by design**. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT-TABLE)

> `timestamp without time zone AT TIME ZONE` ***`zone`*** → `timestamp with time zone`
>
> Converts given time stamp *without* time zone to time stamp *with*
> time zone, assuming the given value is in the named time zone.
>
> `timestamp '2001-02-16 20:38:40' at time zone 'America/Denver'` →
> `2001-02-17 03:38:40+00`

And:

> `timestamp with time zone AT TIME ZONE` ***`zone`*** → `timestamp without time zone`
>
> Converts given time stamp *with* time zone to time stamp *without*
> time zone, as the time would appear in that zone.
>
> `timestamp with time zone '2001-02-16 20:38:40-05' at time zone 'America/Denver'` → `2001-02-16 18:38:40`

See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

Also, you state:

> it is specified that timestamp without timezone is considered to be in the local timezone.

I wouldn't know of such a specification. As the name implies, `timestamp without time zone` isn't considered to be in *any* time zone. It's just an abstract datetime value without time zone information. It's typically *interpreted* to be in the local time zone, but that's not inherent to the type or its values. To place it in a time zone, use the `AT TIME ZONE` construct.

#### Step-by-step breakdown

.. of your misleadingly named columns 2 and 3:

```
SELECT (to_timestamp('2021-10-24 20:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'ASIA/CALCUTTA' AS ist_w_tz
     , (to_timestamp('2021-10-24 20:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')              AT TIME ZONE 'ASIA/CALCUTTA' AS ist_wo_tz
```

1. `(to_timestamp('2021-10-24 20:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi')` .. produces `timestamptz`. That's what the function [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) does. (It might better be named *`to_timestamptz()`*, but that's beyond the scope of this question.)
   The current `timezone` setting is assumed for lack of input.
   Since your input literal is in ISO format, `'2021-10-24 20:00'::timestamptz` would do the same, simpler.
2. `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')` ... produces the corresponding `timestamp` at the time zone UTC.

Now ...

3. `::timestamptz` ... places that timestamp in your local time zone *again* (which typically makes no sense!).
4. `AT TIME ZONE 'ASIA/CALCUTTA'`  ... produces the corresponding `timestamp` at the given time zone.

But ...

3. `::timestamp` ... does nothing at all (the source already being type `timestamp`.
4. `AT TIME ZONE 'ASIA/CALCUTTA'`  ... adds the given time zone to produce `timestamptz`.